# Getting custom fields in gatsby-plugin-feed

Tags: rss, gatsby

I can't figure out how to use the `gatsby-plugin-feed` to add some custom content from my frontmatter to the rss feed. Here is my config:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
      options: {
        query: `
          {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                title
                description
                siteUrl
                site_url: siteUrl
              }
            }
          }
        `,
        feeds: [
          {
            serialize: ({ query: { site, allMarkdownRemark } }) => {
              return allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(edge => ({
                ...edge.node.frontmatter,
                description: edge.node.excerpt,
                url: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + edge.node.fields.slug,
                guid: site.siteMetadata.siteUrl + edge.node.fields.slug,
              }));
            },
            query: `
              {
                allMarkdownRemark(
                  limit: 1000,
                  sort: { order: DESC, fields: [fields___prefix] },
                  filter: { fields: { source: {eq: "posts"}, slug: { ne: null } } }
                ) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      excerpt
                      html
                      fields {
                        slug
                        prefix
                      }
                      frontmatter {
                        title
                        subtitle
                        tags
                        categories
                        youtube
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            `,
            output: '/rss.xml',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

I thought that using the spread operator on the edge.node.frontmatter object would add all of the fields but that resulting item is missing a ton of the frontmatter fields.

I am sure I am missing something, or I don't understand something about rss feeds. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you only have 5 frontmatter fields in your query. Is there any reason not to add them explicitly instead of using the spread operator, or are you just wanting to know why it doesn't work?